# Entering the US while on administrative processing

Tags: usa, working-visas, us-citizens

I change my status to H1B  and my wife to H4 at the end of 2017 I came to Mexico and when I went to get my stamps my visa was put on administrative processing . I know this can take severa months and my wife is pregnant.  She holds a B1 visa too , can she enter the states to give birth ( we have insurance an money ) without hurting our case ?